# start primary key by 1001 in Django model, auto_increment gives error

Tags: python, django, django-models

Please describe how to start the primary key by  1001 in the Django model(database). I found some examples with auto_increment, but it gives me errors of undefined.

Inside the project, we have to alter fields using migrations. So, Please notice that It does not affect our previous data. The database key must increment by 1 when we add another field or row.

Thanks

Comment: Which database are you using? The required SQL command will depend on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the code snippet below:

```py
from django.db import models

def field_start_from_1001():
    """
    Returns the next default value for the with auto-increment fields,
    starts from 1001
    """
    last_entry = YourModel.objects.all().order_by('pk_field').last()
    if last_entry:
        return last_entry.pk_field + 1
    return 1001


class YourModel(model.Model):
    pk_field = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,
                               default=field_start_from_1001)
```